# OpenProcessBlocked even i use SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, true);

Tags: c++

I have a problem, I want to read some values with ReadProcessMemory from a process, this process blocks OpenProcess, now I heard that I just need to Privilege the file who want to do OpenProcess with SE_DEBUG_NAME.

I googled and found this function :

```
BOOL SetPrivilege(
HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
BOOL bEnablePrivilege){
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
LUID luid;

if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
    NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
    lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
    &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
{
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
if (bEnablePrivilege)
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
else
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

// Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
    hToken,
    FALSE,
    &tp,
    sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
    (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
    (PDWORD)NULL))
{
    printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
}

if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

{
    printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
    return FALSE;
}

return TRUE;}
```

Now i tried the following :

bool bStart(std::string szProcessName)
{

```
if (szProcessName.empty())
    return false;
HANDLE hToken;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, true);

if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    return FALSE;

if (!SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE))
{
    std::cout << "SetPrivilege";

    // close token handle
    CloseHandle(hToken);

    // indicate failure
    return false;
}

std::cout << "hi";


HANDLE hSnapshot = (CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0));
if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return false;


bool bFoundProcess = false;
PROCESSENTRY32 PE32 = { sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };
if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &PE32))
{
    do
    {
        if (!szProcessName.compare(PE32.szExeFile))
        {
            m_dwProcessId = (XOR(PE32.th32ProcessID));
            bFoundProcess = true;
            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &PE32));
}

CloseHandle(m_hProcess);

if (!bFoundProcess)
    return false;

m_hProcess = (XOR(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, m_dwProcessId)));
if (m_hProcess == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return false;
```

return true;
}

I don't get any error or anything, but for any reason, the OpenProcess doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `XOR`?. What result did you get back when you checked the error result from `OpenProcess`?

Comment: There are no good reasons that I can think of for OpenProcess() deadlocking.  Exception one, disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @MikeVine XOR is crypting strings, when i use this way for a programm what not block OpenProcess() it works fine !. The programm is just blocking OpenProcess(). Is there something with the code wrong?

Comment: _XOR is crypting strings_ makes no sense - please add your macro/function definition for XOR. Especially you use it in `(XOR(PE32.th32ProcessID))` and `(XOR(OpenProcess(` which really doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Additionally you call openprocesstoken/setprivilege twice and dont check the reutrn values the first time. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`this process blocks OpenProcess`

This means the game's anticheat is blocking process handle creation via a kernel mode anticheat.

There is nothing you can do to bypass this from usermode, you must also make a kernel driver and disable their protection.

The most simple way for them to prevent handle creation is with ObRegisterCallbacks so you will need to reverse engineer their implementation of that.

Keep in mind this technique is from 5+ years ago, they have much more complicated protection now.